# axios interceptors: custom header only being added to OPTIONS request

Tags: javascript, axios

so I have setup an interceptor for axios, and I am adding a custom header to my requests. However, when i check in my server code. The header is only received in `OPTIONS` request.

```
class ChainInterceptors {
  constructor(config) {
    this.cleanConfig = { ...config };
  }
  build() {
    return this.cleanConfig;
  }
}

export class ReqInterceptor extends ChainInterceptors {
  constructor(config) {
    super(config);
  }
  setLog() {
    this.cleanConfig.headers['Respond-By'] = // some value;
    return this;
  }
}
```

And I am implementing it in the following manner:

```
export const request = {
  init() {
    const token = getItem('token');
    const request = axios.create({
      httpsAgent: new https.Agent({ keepAlive: true }),
      baseURL: LOCAL_URL,
      headers: {
        authorization: `bearer ${token}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });
    this.attachInterceptor(request);
    return request;
  },

  attachInterceptor(request) {
    request.interceptors.request.use(config => {
      return new ReqInterceptor(config).setLog().build();
    });
    request.interceptors.response.use(
      response => {
        // response interceptors
      },
      error => {
        // Do something with response error
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );
  },

  get() {
    return this.init().get.apply(null, arguments);
  },

  // and other methods...
};
```

As I said above, the `Respond-By` header is only present in my `OPTIONS` request. Your guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I use the following setting in the **interceptor** to pass token and the **current language**. The current language is the custom header, I need to detect the current language that the user selects from the Client side.

below **config.headers["lang"] = `${lang}`;** is the custom header.

From the server-side, I get it by **_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["lang"]**

```
export function setupAxios(axios, store) {
  axios.interceptors.request.use(
    config => {
      const {
        auth: { authToken },
        i18n: { lang }
      } = store.getState();

      // console.log("language => ", lang);
      // console.log("setupAxios => ", store.getState());

      if (authToken) {
        config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${authToken}`;
        config.headers["lang"] = `${lang}`;
      }
      store.dispatch(httpRequest.actions.startRequest(true));
      return config;
    },
    err => {
      store.dispatch(httpRequest.actions.endRequest(false));
      return Promise.reject(err);
    }
  );
  axios.interceptors.response.use(
    response => {
      store.dispatch(httpRequest.actions.endRequest(false));
      return response;
    },
    err => {
      store.dispatch(httpRequest.actions.endRequest(false));
      return Promise.reject(err);
    }

  );
}
```